# How to loop command multiple times passing output to next command

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to run multiple commands n times, where output of command is passed to next command.

For n=4 `command | command | command | command`

Example:
I want to generate all possible combinations with some chars with some length.

```
./script.sh "ab" 3
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
```

So I created function

```
function looper {
while read line; do 
    for l in $chars
    do echo $line$l
    done;
done;}
```

And I can run like `echo | looper $chars | looper $chars`

Comment: This is what variables are for? Please post an example. What are you trying to achieve? This question is...strange as it is now.

Comment: perhaps you need to write a program that does permutations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation a question more suitable for stackoverflow?

Comment: @Recct In every program I found each char is used 1 time, I need to use all possible combinations of all chars.